# Parse.com .NET SDK: difference between the official and monotouch-bindings

Tags: xamarin.ios

I lately noticed that Parse.com released their SDK for Xamarin.iOS. Up to now, the option was to use the opensource binding https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Parse

What's the difference between the 2 implementation? Is the one from mt-bindings considered deprecated ?

From what I can say, the official Parse sdk:

- is full c# (no binding)
- supports async/await
- but only provide the ParseObject API (no extra, like the loginview, ...)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I've noticed that the Parse.com SDK for Xamarin does not include any of the cacheing abilities. I do think it is more built for async, but it is missing cacheing so I'm debating still using the bindings (which I haven't used before).